# file_get_contents on Word Doc

Tags: php, strpos

I am using the following code attempting to find a "term" in a word document using PHP.
Of course this is not a right way of opening a binary file like a word document, but the malformatted string in "$fileContent" is good enough for me.
However, the "stripos" function is not working as expected when searching for a term that currently is inside the doc.

```
$fileContent = file_get_contents($filePath);
$posFileContent = stripos($fileContent,$term);
if ($posFileContent !== false) {
    echo "Found!!";
    $value += $FACTOR_SEC;
}
```

Observation: doing a var_dump on $fileContent shows the proper content of the doc, with its malformat issues of course, but still the term is there.

More info:

var_dump($term)

string(10) "innovative"

var_dump($fileContent)

string(10240) "��ࡱ�;�� ����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
  ����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������Root
Entry������������������������������������������������������������������������
  ��������!����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
���� �FMicrosoft Word-Dokument MSWordDocWord.Document.8�9�q [Z��ZNormal1$*$3B*OJQJCJmH
sH KHPJnHtH^JaJ_H9BA@���BAbsatz-StandardschriftartF�FHeading ���x$OJQJCJPJ^JaJ.B. Text body ��x /
List^J@""@Caption �x�x$CJ6^JaJ]&�2&Index$^Jd����� � ddPG�Times
New Roman5�Symbol3&�ArialG��Times New Roman5�SimSun5�MangalG�Microsoft
YaHei5��MangalB��h��"�5_��5_' 0
0��������Oh��+'��0|8 @ LXd p��0@@@�{�
�.�@��M ��0� Caolan80 $d��������������b
��Lambda
Developments  About us  Lambda develops innovative software products leading our clients in a road to success.We specialize in
mobile apps, web tools and management systems.Our team is involved in the entire process, beginning where an idea is born, going
through the product specification, until its implementation in an appropriate technology.  &*:>��j
l � � ����������CJ>*5aJ\OJQJ/:;B*ph"""CJ@�6>*5aJ\OJQJCJ$>*5aJ$\CJ8>*5aJ8\
(*
<>� �����$a$"��/
    ��=!�n"�n#�n$�n3P(20����՜.��+,��D��՜.��+,��\����Root
    Entry�������� �F�CompObj����jOle
    ��������1Table������������iSummaryInformation(�����WordDocument������������$DocumentSummaryInformation8������������
    t����������������"

Comment: What exactly your problem is? Where is your question? Have you got any errors? Unexpected results?

Comment: The problem is that I look for a term that actually is inside the string but the function returns it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

After two days of struggling this is the answer:

Microsoft Word encoding adds "\0" characters between all "real characters", so basically the word "hello" is actually "h\0e\0l\0l\0o\0".

The way to search inside the doc is:

```
$fileContent = file_get_contents($filePath);
$termArray = str_split($term);
$newTerm = '';
foreach ($termArray as $charTerm) {
    $newTerm = $newTerm.$charTerm;
    $newTerm = $newTerm."\0";
}
if (stripos($fileContent,$newTerm) !== false) {
    // Term found in doc
}
```